# pass html block as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I know this is a very simple question , I want to know how to pass a html block as a para meter to a function and call that function on very moment that page load .

```
<body>
<section data-role="page" data-theme="ams">
    <section data-role="header" id="content">
        <h1>header ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss</h1>

    </section>
    <section data-role="conents" >
        <p>loruim epsum haha&nbsp;</p>\n<p>hehe told u&nbsp;</p>\n<ol class=\"starpasspro-upper-alpha_ol\">\n<li>gasdfg</li>\n<li>sdfffasd</li>\n<li>asdfffasdf</li>\n<li>asdfasdfasdfasd</li>\n</ol>\n\n<table class=\"table_with_header lsm-tableclass-styles\">\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class=\"lsm_table_heading_1\">Description</td>\n<td class=\"lsm_table_heading_1\">Amount</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Gross salary</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: income tax (£35,000 x 25%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: social security tax (£50,000 x 9%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Net earnings</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Employer’s contribution on social security<br>(£50,000 x10.5%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n\n
        <p><span data-lscp-resource-mimetype=\"image/png\" data-lscp-resource-id=\"51e8db617607942807000032\"></span></p>


    </section>
    <section data-role="footer">
        <p>footer</p>

    </section>
</section>
```

and I want to pass the following html block to my function as a parameter

```
  <p>loruim epsum haha&nbsp;</p>\n<p>hehe told u&nbsp;</p>\n<ol class=\"starpasspro-upper-alpha_ol\">\n<li>gasdfg</li>\n<li>sdfffasd</li>\n<li>asdfffasdf</li>\n<li>asdfasdfasdfasd</li>\n</ol>\n\n<table class=\"table_with_header lsm-tableclass-styles\">\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td class=\"lsm_table_heading_1\">Description</td>\n<td class=\"lsm_table_heading_1\">Amount</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Gross salary</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: income tax (£35,000 x 25%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Less: social security tax (£50,000 x 9%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Net earnings</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Employer’s contribution on social security<br>(£50,000 x10.5%)</td>\n<td>&nbsp;xxxx</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n\n
        <p><span data-lscp-resource-mimetype=\"image/png\" data-lscp-resource-id=\"51e8db617607942807000032\"></span></p>
```

any idea howto do that ?

note this has jquery mobile structures

Comment: Could you post your function? or a version of.

Comment: @ChamZ, i think, you can bind the part of code in ' i.e $mycodeblock = '<p>loruim epsum haha&..."></span></p>', then send this $mycodeblock to your function as parameter, this may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jquery as you can get html as

```
var inputHtml = $("section[data-role='conents']").html();
```

Just pass `inputHtml` to whatever function

Answer (score 1):

```
function yourFunction(htmlBlock){
  // your code
}

// call function and pass Jquery object
yourFunction($('section[data-role="conents"]'));
// call function and pass html code of object
yourFunction($('section[data-role="conents"]').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using jQuery mobile, you could try using

```
var htmlBlock = $('section[data-role="conents"]').html();

yourFunction(htmlBlock);
```